# What's the purpose of the applied "buffer networks" between each level?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass, buffer

The following simulation is performed to analyze the Nyquist diagram of a 3 pole RC low pass filter.

I don't understand why the highlighted networks are required.  How does it work?

[image]

With buffer:

[image]

Without buffer:

[image]

Comment: Can you think what would happen if the buffers were not there, just three cascaded RC filters?

Comment: @Justme; yes, I simulated it. but no conclution.

Comment: Don't jump into conclusions yet, what was the result of the simulation? It must have been different?

Comment: @Justme; I've just attached the simulation results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They isolate RC filters. Each RC filter is a 1st order system with its transfer function. When you put opamp in between you do isolate, so that any forward section doesn't affect the backward section. The equivalent transfer function in Laplace domain is the product of all separate transfer functions.

It's the way for study, you could have many other types of systems instead of 1st order there.

If you connect directly, without an isolating opamp, then each stage interfere with the other, so you can't simply multiply transfer functions in Laplace domain.